# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When the rails application is run, I get the following error which is shown clearly in an image, which is as below;

[image: error.png]

index.html.erb

```
<% balance = 0 %>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table class="table listing text-center">
                <tr class="tr-head">
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>Discount</td>
                    <td>Paid</td>
                    <td>Balance</td>
                </tr>

                    <%= render partial: "xvaziri", collection: @xvaziris %>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

_xvaziri.html.erb

```
<tr  class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

    <td class="col-1"><%= xvaziri.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>
    <td class="col-3"><%= span_with_possibly_red_color xvaziri.description %></td>


    <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


    <% balance += xvaziri.amount.to_f - xvaziri.discount.to_f - xvaziri.paid.to_f %>

    <% color = balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

    <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

</tr>
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I defined <% balance = 0 %> in the partial it worked for me.

Comment: You don't have a `balance` variable. Declaring variables on the view, is not a good practice, neither to do calculations on the view. You should do those things in the back-end (preferably on the model) and set the instance variables on you controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you show me with example of my code  so that I can prefer your suggestion in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a variable that is local to the index view in the partial, which has no access to it. Either pass it through as a local to the partial:

```
<%= render partial: "xvaziri", collection: @xvaziris, balance: balance %>
```

or make it available to the whole request

```
<% @balance = 0 %>
```

I would recommend the latter since you will be using it in many places. Update all uses of the variable to `@balance` and you'll be set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with both none of them worked.

Comment: When I defined <% balance = 0 %> in the partial it worked for me.

Comment: @MuhammadYaseen That will stop the error, but prevent the balance from summing across all renders of that partial (i.e. if you have multiple `@xvaziris`s). You're resetting the value to 0 at the beginning of each iteration. Using `@balance` will let it persist and sum each iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, you are absolutely right and finally I proceed as per your suggestion and got the correct result.